# How to get textView's information before closing activity with kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a activity that have one EditView .
I want when this activity closed the information that user entered, adds to recyclerView item.
When i do it the information is null.

I'm sorry for the grammatical errors. I would be happy if you remind me of the bad ones.

My code is:

```
override fun finish(){
    list.add(textView.text)
    adapter.notifyDatasetChanched()
    super.finish()
}
```

Comment: Judging by that snippet of code you are not preforming any saving to local or remote database so what is the purpose of code because after `super.finish()` is called `Activity` is destroyed and garbage collected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to answer without knowing the full scenario. Depending on what you are doing I would do one of:

1) I would instead override the `onStop` function. It is called before the activity is finished.

```
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    list.add(textView.text)
    adapter.notifyDatasetChanched()
}
```

2) Perform the list adding to the adapter before wherever you are calling `finish()`. This is the cleaner solution.

Note: I am not sure if it will actually render to the screen. It may, it may not. It seems you are modifying a view as you are finishing the activity in which that view is held. When the activity finishes (which will be right after you notify the adapter), the view will be detached and there will be nothing to update.

Answer (score 0):

yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

```
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // you can call or do what you want with your EditText here

           list.add(textView.text)
adapter.notifyDatasetChanched()
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
    });
}
```